# How to disable menu item of bottom navigation view?

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design

How can I disable a material design bottom navigation menu item? I can set `.isClickable = false` but this doesn't show the menu item as disabled, similar to a button. I can't do `.isEnabled`, the API won't allow it.

BottomNavigationView XML

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/menu_item_1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@color/colorDark"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu">
```

Menu XML

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
      
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_home"
        android:title="Home"
        android:icon="@drawable/home_button"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

Activity

```
class Something : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var mHomeBtn: BottomNavigationItemView
    override fun onCreate(...) {
        mHomeBtn = this.findViewById(R.id.action_home)
        mHomeBtn.isClickable = false  // <--- will make it unable to click but won't show disabled
        mHomeBtn.isEnabled = false    // <--- will throw an error
        mHomeBtn.setOnClickListener(this)
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Are you getting a null pointer exception ?

Comment: i am not getting null pointer. i am trying to figure out how to grey out the bottom navigation menu item when disabled. currently, it will prevent clicking on it but it shows the same color, not greyed out.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should get the menu of your `BottomNavigationView`  and then find and disable the `MenuItem` that you want. In code it could be done as follows

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    // Find the bottom navigation view, (Use correct ID)
    // menu_item_1 is probably not a good ID for a navigation view
    val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)

    // Find the menu item and then disable it
    navView.menu.findItem(R.id.navigation_home).isEnabled = false
}
```

Comment: this "worked" similarly as .isClickable=false would but it doesn't show my menu item disabled. how can i show the menu item disabled? similarly how a button would show "greyed" out if it was disabled.

Comment: This code disables the menu item, which will change its color to grey. If color is not chaging that means you have modified some color property from default to some custom setting. Probably background color

Answer (score 1):

Adding to mightyWOZ answer

```
navView.menu.findItem(R.id.navigation_home).isCheckable = false
```

this makes the menu item disabled (grey).